# Morphism of vector bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

I have some doubts on the definition of morphism of vector bundles.
My notes say: "*Let $ E, E'$ be vector bundles over the same B. A morphism of vector bundles is a morphism of bundles $f:E\rightarrow E'$ such that for each $p\in B$ the map $f|_{E_p}:E_{p}\rightarrow E'_{f(p)}$ is linear.*"
My first doubt is the following: if $f$ is restricted to $E_p$, then it's clear that $f|_{E_p}$ has domain $E_p$, but I think that it has target in $E'_p$, and not in $E'_{f(p)}$. I've thought this because, if $\pi$ and $\pi'$ are the projections on $B$ of $E$ and $E'$ respectively, then, since $f$ is a morphism of bundles, $f={\pi'}^{-1}\circ \pi$. So $f(E_p)=f(\pi^{-1}(p))={\pi'}^{-1}(\pi(\pi^{-1}(p)))={\pi'}^{-1}(p)=E'_p$.
Am I wrong?
Can someone give me some clarifications?

Comment: I think you're right, but the formula $f=\pi′^{−1} \circ \pi$ isn't, because $\pi'$ isn't injective.

Comment: If you had looked into any other book (or just Wikipedia), it would have given you the right definition.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. It might be a typo in the book or in the notes.

$f(p)$ just syntactically doesn't make sense, as $p\in B$ and $f:E\to E'$.

Comment: Yes, there's a syntax error, but it is not universally accepted that the bundle map must cover the identity on the base. That is, it may be that there is a diffeomorphism $g\colon B\to B$ so that $f|_{E_p}\colon E_p \to E'_{g(p)}$.

Comment: @Asal Beag Dubh: you're right, $\pi'$ isn't injective! But anyway, as Berci says, $f(p)$ doesn't make any sense...

Comment: @Berci: thanks!